# Azure web app serving old files

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I have a CI pipeline using VSTS to deploy an asp .net core application to a web app hosted on Azure

Every time I successfully deploy to the web app it seems that Azure isn't serving the latest changes to the sites homepage. I have verified using the Kudu advanced tools that the files are in fact the latest but it seems that Azure isn't serving them and is somehow serving older files.

This seems to only affect any pages from the home controller as all other routes and static files seem to update fine.

Does anyone know why Azure may be showing older or cached version of certain pages?

Comment: Did you try restarting the appservice?

Comment: Yep, restarted several times

Comment: Not sure if your browser is caching it. Can you try clearing your browser cache and try again?

Comment: try incognito mode

Comment: Its not azure. Looks like your browser or proxy server is caching.

Answer (score 0):

If your web app uses local cache, you need to restart your site to get the latest changes. Check if you have set the value of WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION to ‘Always’ in your Application settings.

Also, set WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE value to zero and check.

You have mentioned that files are updated in Kudu console. As others suggested, if you haven’t done this already, try clearing browser cookies, history and cache. Also, test this on another browser or private mode and see if that helps.